# Linux port blocked - This site can't be reached, refused to connect

Tags: linux, networking, port, tcp, access-point

I set my linux as an access point, and then run simple web-server that print "hello world" at port 3000.

and connect it with my smart phone successfully.

in linux terminal, `http://localhost:3000` works well.

But in smart phone,

If I access to `http://172.24.1.105:3000`, can't connect to it. (172.24... is ap's ip)

the chrome's error message is

> This site can't be reached. 172.24.1.105 refused to connect

I searched Google (https://serverfault.com/questions/725262/what-causes-the-connection-refused-message) and I suspicious linux's firewall.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/prj/ap_server $ sudo tcpdump -n icmp
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

... when I access to port 3000, 

15:07:13.102750 IP 192.168.0.3 > 168.126.63.2: ICMP 192.168.0.3 udp port 42531 unreachable, length 386
```

the log is above. so I couldn't reach ap's webserver.

so I wonder two things...

**1. How can I disable to its port block?**

**2. in tcpdump log, I access to port 3000 actually, why the log print port 42531?**

Plus)

even I type `sudo service iptables stop`, the problem is not solved

`sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 3000` logs:

`**tcp6 0 0 :::3000 :::* LISTEN 1999/nodejs**`

+I followed this tutorial-> https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/ .

and there is ipv4 setting.

Comment: This is a good example of why you shouldn't rewrite error messages. There is a world of difference between 'couldn't be reached' and 'connection refused'.

Comment: @EJP what are you mean..? couldn't be reached and connection refused comes together... I just bring it from chrome message

Comment: I'm talking about the Chrome message. If the site couldn't be reached, it couldn't possibly have refused the connection. One or the other happened. Not both. Chrome should not have rewritten the error message. It has just caused confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it on your mobile it will work on Live IP (externel) address

if it is working fine on local address (localhost) and not on live IP then 
enable routing from your router

and allow that specific port it will work fine.

Comment: in mobile, localhost and external ip both connect refused.

Comment: But the problem is solved now. The external IP on my mobile device is `172.24.1.105` so I tried to connect with this ip and failed, I tried to connect `172.24.1.1` now connect success.

Comment: I set my dns, dhcp to `interface=wlan0, listen-address=172.24.1.1, dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h ` like this. I confused listen-address and external ip. do you know what is different? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

my dhcp set was

```
interface=wlan0      # Use interface wlan0  
listen-address=172.24.1.1 # Explicitly specify the address to listen on  
bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface to make sure we aren't sending things elsewhere  
server=8.8.8.8       # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS  
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names  
bogus-priv           # Never forward addresses in the non-routed address spaces.  
dhcp-range=172.24.1.50,172.24.1.150,12h # Assign IP addresses between 172.24.1.50 and 172.24.1.150 with a 12 hour lease time
```

like above.

I tried to connect the external ip(`172.24.1.105`) that I can see on mobile continuously but got failed. but when I tried with `172.24.1.1`, then success.

I don't know why. maybe there is accurate ip address and something in mobile is temporal.

Answer (score -3):

See similar topic at [Node JS not listening to port 1337 on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152460/node-js-not-listening-to-port-1337-on-server#31152493)

Your web server is not listening remote address.

Comment: Not a similar topic. Completely different message, cause, and cure.